# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' after installing with pip

Tags: python, sockets

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'requests'
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\MMT\apiMSSQL.py", line 1, in <module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I tried to import module requests in Python. I'm sure that I have installed it, it also is shown in pip list.

Comment: make sure the python interpreter for pip that you are using aligns with the python interpreter you're using to run your script

Comment: if you're using an environment, check if it's the same env where you have the `requests` lib installed

Comment: `pip install requests`

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed the requests module in a different Python environment than the one you're using. Check which Python environment you're using by running `python --version`. Try specifying the correct environment, or reinstall the requests module by running `pip uninstall requests` followed by `pip install requests`. This should give you the latest version of the module.

Answer (score 1):

change your python interpreter by clicking on the left bottom of the vscode and then select the recommended one on the top.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMHSk.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).